# Limiting decimal places in print output, in Dart

Tags: dart

Sorry, noob question
I'm searching for how to limit the amount of decimal points printed.
I found this:

```dart
print(price.toStringAsFixed(2));    // which worked great in another script
```

but how do I limit to 1 decimal point in the script below? I'm getting 14 decimal places :)

```dart
String inTemp = stdin.readLineSync();
int temp = int.parse(inTemp);

switch (selection) {
  case 'A':
    print('$temp degrees Celcius is ${temp * 1.8 + 32} degrees Fahrenheit');
```

*I'm sure it's something obvious but I can't figure it out.

Cheers for any help.

## ** Edit: So I can do it by adding new variables like below, but I'd still like to know how/if it can be done in the original print statement.

```dart
String inTemp = stdin.readLineSync();
  int temp = int.parse(inTemp);
  num temp1 = (temp * 1.8 + 32);
  num temp2 = ((temp - 32) / 1.8);

  switch (selection) {
    case 'A':
      print('$temp degrees Celcius is ${temp1.toStringAsFixed(1)} degrees Fahrenheit');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do the same thing to the number, just inside the `${...}`:

```dart
case 'A':
  print('$temp degrees Celcius is ${(temp * 1.8 + 32).toStringAsFixed(1)}'
        ' degrees Fahrenheit');
```

Comment: I swear I tried that already. Must have made an error in the brackets. Thanks for the answer mate.